# Trying to get twitter profile information in c#

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

I'm trying to retrieve profile data for an authenticated twitter user using the [home_timeline](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/home_timeline) API call. I've got a specific method used for this purpose and at this point I'm just trying to return the JSON string to verify it works, but I'm getting a 400 error.

```
public string getProfile(){
            // set your own keys and screen name
            var oauth_consumer_key = "consumerKeyHere";
            var oAuthConsumerSecret = "consumerSecretHere";
            var oAuthUrl = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json";
            var oauth_token_secret = "tokenSecretHere";
            // Authenticate
            var authHeaderFormat = "Basic {0}";

            var postBody = "grant_type=client_credentials";
            var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
                new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));
            var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow
                           - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();
            var oauth_token = token.access_token; // this token is generated by another class (token) where I retrieve the access token. Verified that authentication works.

            // oauth implementation details
            var oauth_version = "1.0";
            var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

            // create oauth signature
            var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                         "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}";

            var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                oauth_consumer_key,
                oauth_nonce,
                oauth_signature_method,
                oauth_timestamp,
                oauth_token,
                oauth_version
            );

            baseString = string.Concat("GET&", Uri.EscapeDataString("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json"), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

            var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

            string oauth_signature;
            using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))  {
                oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(
                    hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
            }

            // create the request header
            var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"{0}\", oauth_nonce=\"{1}\", " +
                               "oauth_signature=\"{2}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{3}\", " +
                               "oauth_timestamp=\"{4}\", oauth_token=\"{5}\", " +
                               "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

            var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
            );

            HttpWebRequest authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(oAuthUrl);
            authRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
            authRequest.Method = "GET";
            authRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
            authRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;

            WebResponse authResponse = authRequest.GetResponse();
            // deserialize into an object
            using (authResponse)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(authResponse.GetResponseStream())) {
                    String js = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    return js;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My arguments were in the wrong order for authHeader:

```
var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"{0}\", oauth_nonce=\"{1}\", " +
                               "oauth_signature=\"{2}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{3}\", " +
                               "oauth_timestamp=\"{4}\", oauth_token=\"{5}\", " +
                               "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

            var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
            );
```

Comment: You have `oauth_token=\"{5}\"` and `oauth_signature` as the 5th parameter. How could that ever work?

Comment: Oh, unless you're showing how your arguments were in the wrong order. My bad.